# Webcrawler skipping URLS

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, rest-client

I'm writing a program that scans for vulnerable websites, I happen to know that there are a couple sites that have vulnerabilities, and return a SQL syntax error, however, when I run the program, it skips over these sites and doesn't output that they where found or output that they where saved into a file. This program is being used for pentesting and all owners of sites are made aware of the vulnerability.

Source:

```
def get_urls
  info("Searching for possible SQL vulnerable sites.")
  @agent = Mechanize.new
  page = @agent.get('http://www.google.com/')
  google_form = page.form('f')
  google_form.q = "#{SEARCH}"
  url = @agent.submit(google_form, google_form.buttons.first)
  url.links.each do |link|
    if link.href.to_s =~ /url.q/
      str = link.href.to_s
      str_list = str.split(%r{=|&})
      urls = str_list[1]
      next if str_list[1].split('/')[2] == "webcache.googleusercontent.com"
      urls_to_log = urls.gsub("%3F", '?').gsub("%3D", '=')
      success("Site found: #{urls_to_log}")
      File.open("#{PATH}/temp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt", "a+") {|s| s.puts("#{urls_to_log}'")}
    end
  end
  info("Possible vulnerable sites dumped into #{PATH}/temp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt")
end

def check_if_vulnerable
  info("Checking if sites are vulnerable.")
  IO.read("#{PATH}/temp/SQL_sites_to_check.txt").each_line do |parse|
    begin
      Timeout::timeout(5) do
        parsing = Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get("#{parse.chomp}")) 
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error, RestClient::ResourceNotFound, RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified, Errno::ECONNABORTED, Mechanize::ResponseCodeError, RestClient::InternalServerError => e
      if e
        warn("URL: #{parse.chomp} failed with error: [#{e}] dumped to non_exploitable.txt")
        File.open("#{PATH}/lib/non_exploitable.txt", "a+"){|s| s.puts(parse)}
      else 
        success("SQL syntax error discovered in URL: #{parse.chomp} dumped to SQL_VULN.txt")
        File.open("#{PATH}/lib/SQL_VULN.txt", "a+"){|vuln| vuln.puts(parse)}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Example of usage:

```
[22:49:29 INFO]Checking if sites are vulnerable.
[22:49:53 WARNING]URL: http://www.police.bd/content.php?id=275' failed with error: [execution expired] dumped to non_exploitable.txt
```

File containing the URLs:

```
http://www.bible.com/subcat.php?id=2'
http://www.cidko.com/pro_con.php?id=3'
http://www.slavsandtat.com/about.php?id=25'
http://www.police.bd/content.php?id=275'
http://www.icdcprage.org/index.php?id=10'
http://huawei.com/en/plugin.php?id=hwdownload'
https://huawei.com/en/plugin.php?id=unlock'
https://facebook.com/profile.php?id'
http://www.footballclub.com.au/index.php?id=43'
http://www.mesrs.qc.ca/index.php?id=1525'
```

As you can see the program skips over 3 URLs and goes straight to the fourth one, why?

Am I doing something wrong to where this will happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". Your code won't run as is. It's important for consistency that it work without us having to modify it to run. You have constants that are not defined and two methods that are never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that `rescue` block is where it should be. You are not doing anything with the content you fetch in `parsing = Nokogiri::HTML(RestClient.get("#{parse.chomp}"))` and for the first three it maybe just works hence no exception and no error output. Add some output after that line to see them being fetched.

Comment: So I should add some `puts` to display the HTML being fetched, is basically what you're saying?

Comment: That and think about what to do with the parsed content that doesn't raise any exception at all.